# No php 7.3 imap module in Ubuntu 18

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, php-imap

I have an old server running ubuntu 18 (which I cannot upgrade) and PHP 7.3.

**lsb_release -a**

> No LSB modules are available. Distributor ID: Ubuntu Description:
> Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS Release:        18.04 Codename:       bionic

**php -v**

> PHP 7.3.9-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Sep  2 2019 12:54:24) ( NTS )

I need imap extension for PHP 7.3 but cannot install it through apt, php-imap would give me 7.2 version and php7.3-imap is not found.

**apt search php-imap**

> php-imap/bionic,now 1:7.2+60ubuntu1 all [installed]

**apt search php7.3-imap**

> Sorting... Done Full Text Search... Done

**apt search php7.3**

> libapache2-mod-php7.3/now 7.3.9-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64
> [installed,local]   server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language
> (Apache 2 module)
>
> php7.3/now 7.3.9-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 all [installed,local]
> server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (metapackage)
>
> php7.3-bz2/now 7.3.9-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64
> [installed,local]   bzip2 module for PHP
>
> php7.3-cli/now 7.3.9-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64
> [installed,local]   command-line interpreter for the PHP scripting
> language
>
> php7.3-common/now 7.3.9-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64
> [installed,local]   documentation, examples and common module for PHP
>
> php7.3-curl/now 7.3.9-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64
> [installed,local]   CURL module for PHP
>
> php7.3-gd/now 7.3.9-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64
> [installed,local]   GD module for PHP
>
> php7.3-json/now 7.3.9-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64
> [installed,local]   JSON module for PHP
>
> php7.3-mbstring/now 7.3.9-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64
> [installed,local]   MBSTRING module for PHP
>
> php7.3-mysql/now 7.3.9-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64
> [installed,local]   MySQL module for PHP
>
> php7.3-opcache/now 7.3.9-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64
> [installed,local]   Zend OpCache module for PHP
>
> php7.3-readline/now 7.3.9-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64
> [installed,local]   readline module for PHP
>
> php7.3-xml/now 7.3.9-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64
> [installed,local]   DOM, SimpleXML, WDDX, XML, and XSL module for PHP
>
> php7.3-zip/now 7.3.9-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64
> [installed,local]   Zip module for PHP

What would be my options?

Could I install it manually and enable it through php.ini?
Or would there be any repo that has it and still works for ubuntu 18?
I also have ppa:ondrej/php installed, but required module is not there.

Thank you in advance.